# iOS 8 icon badge not updating when receiving remote notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iOS app that uses remote notifications. All works fine but I have noticed that the icon badge doesn't show any number when a notification is received.

I ask for permissions in this way in my AppDelegate:

```
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Is there anything more that I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the content of your remote notification?  Does it include a badge value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push notification payload should contain value with `"badge"` key, that will automatically update the app icon's badge.